# If $S$ is any set, prove that it is impossible to find a mapping of $S$ $onto$ $S^*$.What does "$onto$" means here?

Tags: functions, terminology

I was studying about functions and I had a general query regarding a term quite oftenly used in various contexts. I am taking an example to show it. For eg: If $S$ is any set, prove that it is impossible to find a mapping of $S$ *onto* $S^*$.

This was a problem given in the book. Here, $S$ denotes an arbitrary non-empty set and $S^*$ denotes the power set of $S$. Now, my question is what does that "*onto*" means here? Is it referring to the *onto functions* (that $f:S\longrightarrow S^*$ and $f$ is an onto function , as well) or is it talking about in a more general sense , like,  " A function which maps $S$ onto $S^*$ " is basically equivalent to saying as "A function which maps  from $S$  to $S^*$" (nothing special here , just in a normal sense of saying $f:S\longrightarrow S^*$ and $f$ maybe onto or it may not be ). Which one does it refer to(in general)? I am not quite getting it...Nothing is mentioned about this in the book...

Comment: "Onto" usually means "surjective" in (old-fashioned) texts.

Comment: What is "an onto function"?? Doesn't seem grammatical; "onto" is a preppsition, not an adjective, AFAIK.

Comment: Same thing it always means.   The point is that there's always an element of the power set that's not "hit".

Comment: What it ends up boiling down to is, it's not possible because,  in terms of cardinality,  the power set is strictly bigger.

Comment: @bof: An "onto function" is somewhat dated terminology for "surjective function." Oops, I see SAAD already answered that, but I'll leave this here for the tag.

Comment: @BrianTung so it means that it's talking about an onto function , right? An onto function from $S$ to $S^*$, right?

Comment: Don't use math mode for italics. To get italic text, use regular text enclosed by asterisks.

Comment: @BrianTung The terminology I learned must be even more dated: we called a surjective mapping $f:A\to B$ "a function mapping $A$ onto $B$" instead of the ugly and ungrammatical "an onto function".

Comment: In the title and again in the first paragraph $S$ is "any" set, but in the second paragraph it's a "non-empty" set. No need to make an exception for the empty set.

Comment: @bof: It may be ugly, but during the time that usage was more common, it was consistently used and understood. It might have been frowned upon by non-mathematician grammarians, but I would not call it ungrammatical. There are examples too numerous to count where nouns have been verbed (and verbs have been nouned); that this is an example of a preposition being adjectived may make it more exotic, but it's still part of a productive process.

Comment: Of course, the fuller statement was also extant, but I'm not sure that makes it necessarily older...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can answer.   The reference is definitely to the very famous Cantor's theorem.

Here onto certainly doesn't merely mean "to" or "into";  but rather it means "surjective".

In fact, pretty much whenever one, especially a mathematician, speaks of an "onto" function,  one is going to mean a surjective one.  In other words,  if $f:A\to B$, then for every $b\in B$ there's an $a\in A$ such that $f(a)=b$.

Mathematicians don't use that terminology loosely,  because of the importance of injections,  surjections, bijections and all that good stuff.

But I doubly know that's the meaning here, because the content of Cantor's theorem is that there's no surjection from a set to its power set.

---

Besides,  there's always a function "into" a given set:  for instance a constant function.   Without any restrictions on the type of function.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I do get it now....Thank you so much!...

Comment: You bet @Franklin thanks

Answer (score 0):

A mapping of S onto S* is a mapping that for every element in S* there is exactly one element in S.
In every mapping we have a unique element in S* for each element is S. it means that the number of elements of S must be equal or bigger than S* (we cant have 2 image in S* for one element in S).
If S has n elements then S* must have 2**n elements (number of subsets).
For any integers 2**n is bigger than n.
So its impossible to find a mapping.